# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getFirestore' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have this issue with react firebase/firestore

error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getFirestore' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

```
export const createTask = (task) => {
    return(dispatch, getState, {getFirestore}) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();

        firestore.collection('task').add({
            ...task,
            author: 'Steven',
            authorId: 1223,
            createdAt: new Date()
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({type: CREATE_TASK, task })
        }).catch((err)=>{
            dispatch({type: CREATE_TASK_ERROR, err})
        })

    }
}
```

Anyone knows what to look for?

Comment: const firestore = getFirestore;

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not with the code that you shared but with the way how you used it.

This should be working:

```
const myTask=createTask(aTask);
myTask(dispatch, getState, {getFirestore});
```